# No bootable image found (kali 202.4 uefi mode)

Tags: linux, debian, kali-linux

I'm having problem booting into my installed kali 2020.4 using the gpt partition table. I'm left with the no bootable image found unless i give a pathway on where to boot (esc>>f9>>efi file>>(path way)>>kali>>grub64.efi) before I'm presented with the login page.

I've tried updating my bios from my pc provider(hp zbook 15 g2),

I've changed the partion table on my bootable usb using rufus

I've erased the pre-installed win10 (legacy boot mode) and choose the option of using my entire hdd during installation of kali 2020.4

I've changed my bios node from legacy to uefi which should work with gpt partition table all to no avail.

Please anybody with the solution should do well to share with me so that my pc can boot into kali like any other pc without me giving a pathway

Comment: Welcome, Install it in legacy mode on GPT table. The UEFI will cause some problems with the unsigned kernel modules driver.

Comment: how would i go about that

Comment: Create 1M `bios_grub` partition with the partition manager, it will be grub during the grub install step. boot in legacy mode

Comment: thanks bro let me go try it out

Comment: I tried it out bro but it didn't work but I made it work by putting on the customized boot from my bios and then giving it the path EFI/kali/grubx64.efi and it worked